# Why are they called the complimentary function and the particular integral?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, terminology

We know that an ordinary differential equation of the form $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+a\frac{dy}{dx}+by=f(x)$$ is a linear, nonhomogeneous differential equation. Here, $a,b$ are constants and $f(x)$ is a specified function.

Its general solution is given by $$y(x)=y_1(x)+y_2(x)$$ where $y_1(x)$ is the solution of the homogeneous part
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+a\frac{dy}{dx}+by=0,$$
called the complimentary function and the rest, $y_2(x)$ is called the particular integral that depends on $f(x)$.

Does anyone know why $y_1$ is called the complementary function and $y_2$, the particular integral?

Comment: $y_2$ is a "particular" solution in the sense that though there are many options for $y_2$, you only need to find one (particular) example.  Don't know the reason for "complementary".

Comment: Note that the words “complementary” and “complimentary” mean completely different things!

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comment by David, you take any "particular" solution of the *inhomogeneous* equation and "complement" it with the solutions of the *homogeneous* version of the equation to get the general solution.

That this works is due to the linear nature of the equation, as with any linear system $Ax=b$ the affine solution space is parallel to the kernel of $A$. So if any solution $x_0$ exists and is fixed, then any other solution satisfies $A(x-x_0)=Ax-Ax_0=b-b=0$, that is, $x\in x_0+\ker A$.